# Calling Microsoft Graph API from Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I am not sure if I am on the right path, but I am attempting to retrieve my contacts within an Azure Function. I don't need to present a login as this is only for my account. I just want to be able to retrieve my Contacts from the Graph without having to explicitly authenticate. Is this possible? My attempts have failed and I ultimately get stuck trying to add permission...

[image: Add Permission]

When I click to add Permission, I get this error:

[image: Error]

I am trying to use AAD to authenticate. I tried creating the function within the Portal and also from VS. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow the steps below to fix the issue.

1.Navigate to the `Authentication / Authorization` of your function app, click the red frame part like the screenshot.

[image]

2. Go to `Manage Permissions` -> `Add` -> select the `Windows Azure Active Directory` API and `Sign in and read user profile` permission

   [image]

Then refresh the portal, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the help!!